# Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name on this ManagedType when using joins

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've had an issue when performing join followed by a query involving where in JPA. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for the past 6 hours to no avail.

```
 float max_price = 3;
 CriteriaQuery<Browar> cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Browar.class);
 Root<Browar> br = cb.from(Browar.class);
 Join<Browar,Piwo> j = br.join("piwa");
 ParameterExpression<Float> p = em.getCriteriaBuilder().parameter(Float.class);
 cb.multiselect(j,br);
 cb.where(em.getCriteriaBuilder().le(j.get("cena"), p));
 cb.distinct(true);
 TypedQuery<Browar> q = em.createQuery(cb);
 q.setParameter(p,max_price);
 List<Browar> bl = q.getResultList();
```

The code throws

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [cena] on this ManagedType [local.kamilsuchecki.mavenproject1.Browar]
> at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:148)
> at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:119)
> at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:44)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:111)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
> at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
> at local.kamilsuchecki.mavenproject1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:169)

at `cb.where(em.getCriteriaBuilder().le(j.get("cena"), p));`

A similar issue comes up when I try to use

```
em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Browar e JOIN e.piwa aboslutley_not_browar WHERE aboslutley_not_browar.cena <= :p").setParameter("p",max_price).getResultList();
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: cena of: local.kamilsuchecki.mavenproject1.Browar [SELECT DISTINCT e FROM local.kamilsuchecki.mavenproject1.Browar e JOIN e.piwa aboslutley_not_browar WHERE aboslutley_not_browar.cena <= :p]
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
> at local.kamilsuchecki.mavenproject1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:175)

I'm thinking that there is maybe something wrong with my entity classes, in which case i'm including these as well

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
public class Browar implements Serializable {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id 
    private String name;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long wartosc; 

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Browar> piwa;
}



@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
@ToString
@Entity
public class Piwo implements Serializable {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id 
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private float cena;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Browar browar;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Hibernate version 5.4.30? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I was using 5.4.29, but after updating dependencies the issue persists. I filled out an issue report.